# Page number on quotes generated in the quite object

Tags: apex, quote

Is there a way to put page numbers on quotes in Salesforce ?
Under

> Setup > Quote > Temoplates

In the quote editor I can't seem to find a page number option, Anyone know how to add that to quotes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, we can not able to add Page Number on Quote Template. Seems, it is a [Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Ix7P) on appExchange.